# phpmyadmin corrupt configuration cause sporadic 403 forbidden

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm running phpmyadmin on ubuntu 18.04.
I made a update to the newest version of phpmyadmin (4:5.1.1+dfsg1-3+bionic1)) and run in some trouble, because I enter a wrong database password. Therefore the software was updates but not the database. Of cause phpmyadmin show some errors after it.
To get rid of the problem again, I did an apt remove and then an apt install again. Unfortunately the config-DB (DB-Name: phpmyadmin) is not rebuilt.
Then I dropped the complete config DB (with a backup before) and did an apt remove and an apt install. Unfortunately still without success. Question now is, how do I get phpmyadmin to create a default configuration db again. The masks/prompts for DB password are not displayed anymore.

The error in phpmyadmin I get is:
403 forbidden when posting from https://.../phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/config/get
But only sometimes (at about every 3rd request).

Edit:
mysql log shows no error

apache log shows also no error for the request, that fails, but hints to a 421 (misdirected):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [01/Mar/2023:08:28:39 +0000] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/config/set HTTP/1.1" 403 421 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
```

so the 403 is not direct from apache.

Now I get also these randomly 403 on my Wordpress too (not so often, every 100 request), so seems to be something "deeper" in the system.

I take any hint to search!

Comment: The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

Could be sooooo many things, but to start, have you looked at your timeouts?  If your query is too big, it will hang, and another connection would be denied during that time.

Comment: If you are lucky enough to be able to have access to the server directly, check out MySQL Workbench .. its WAY better than phpadmin, and really phpadmin should only be used in cases where you are FORCED to do it through a remote console or something.   Download even Ubuntu version here -->
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/